# How to show page numbering numerically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there any way I can change page numbering using C# instead of using ASP.NET as happened here,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" 
              runat="server" 
              AllowPaging=true 
              PageSize=5 
              PagerSettings-PageButtonCount=20 >
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this..

```
gvData.pagesize=somenumber;
gvData.pagersettings.Mode=some mode;
```

**pageisze** to change the size of the page and

**pagersettings.Mode** to change the numbering mode

Comment: thanks, but Can I use same with SPGridView as well ?  for SPGridView I am not able to get "Mode" property

Answer (score 3):

You mean this?

```
gvData.PageSize = 6;
gvData.PageCount = 10;
gvData.AllowPaging=true;
...
```

Comment: Sorry I confused you, I actually want to change page numbering into Numeric or Previous

Comment: No problem. I think you already got the answer from @coder. Good luck !